# How to set CSS class/style to particular column in GridX?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

I would like to set the custom style or CSS class on the column of Dojo's **GridX** to customize the content layout (centering of text, background color, font etc.).

For example, I have now the following block (rendered):

```
<td colid="extern" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="gridxCell  " aria-describedby="gridx_Grid_0-extern">
    <div class="gridxCellWidget" id="dijit__WidgetsInTemplateMixin_10" widgetid="dijit__WidgetsInTemplateMixin_10">
    </div>
</td>
```

I'd like to tell GridX renderer to append the class `extern` to either `td` or `div` (or both).

Is there a standard way to do so (a parameter to structure, for example)? If no, in which code fragment I could build my custom hook, that would do namely what I have described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to pass style and class property in the column definition, something like

```javascript
{
 id: some_id,
 field: some_field,
 style: "text-align: left",
 class: "extern"
}
```

I'm still researching the gridx and I don't know what can be done here, but this worked for me for now. I will try to pass a css class in the column definition.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, this is not documented, but 'class' also works